# O que é $_GET['path']?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber o que significa quando alguém usa `$_GET['path']`? O que seria o `path`? Achei que o `$_GET` só receberia informações da URL.

```
public function get_url_data () {

    // Verifica se o parâmetro path foi enviado
    if ( isset( $_GET['path'] ) ) {

    // Captura o valor de $_GET['path']
    $path = $_GET['path'];

    // Limpa os dados
                        $path = rtrim($path, '/');
                        $path = filter_var($path, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

    // Cria um array de parâmetros
    $path = explode('/', $path);

    // Configura as propriedades
    $this->controlador  = chk_array( $path, 0 );
    $this->controlador .= '-controller';
    $this->acao         = chk_array( $path, 1 );

    // Configura os parâmetros
    if ( chk_array( $path, 2 ) ) {
    unset( $path[0] );
    unset( $path[1] );

    // Os parâmetros sempre virão após a ação
    $this->parametros = array_values( $path );
    }Fim if
```

Se possível informar o que é `path`.

Comment: `$_GET` é diferente de `get['']` !!! talvez esse `get` seja outra coisa um `array`

Comment: Que eu saiba isto não existe, talvez seja um array criado no seu código chamado `$get` que contenha o elemento `path`. O que existe é `$_GET['parametro']`

Comment: sol25lua, coloque o código onde está isso. Sem o contexto é impossível afirmar. Você já devia ter reparado isso nas suas outras perguntas, que só deu para responder quando você postou o trecho do código. Por favor, tenha mais atenção quando for perguntar aqui e leia o guia de [ask].

Comment: Tudo bem me desculpe vou postar por completo, vou editar a pergunta

Comment: @sol25lua não precisa pedir desculpas de nada fique tranquilo ... Ao poucos vai pegando o jeito ...

Comment: Sim, o `$_GET` pega informações passadas na própria url. `$_GET['path']` vai pegar o valor de um parâmetro chamado `path` presente na URL, se esse parâmetro existir.

Comment: Porque o espanto com o `path`? Nada de complicado, veja:  `http://dominio.com?nome=sol25lua` OU `http://dominio.com?path=sol25lua` recuperando o valor  `$_GET['nome']` OU  `$_GET['path']` ambos retornam `sol25lua`

Comment: O método $_GET é usado para receber variáveis através do URL (Link que insere no browser), certamente já viu em alguns sites um link desta forma `www.exemplo.com/index.php?path=sol25lua` .
O ponto de ? é a forma de declarar que a seguir são variáveis.  Após o ? podemos começar a declarar as variáveis. neste exemplo estamos a definir a variável `path` com o valor `sol25lua`

Comment: Entendi, mas se na URL tiver mais de um parâmetro, dessa forma: http://dominio.com?nome=sol25lua?cidade=curitiba ao recuperar o valor de $_GET['path'] qual seria o resultado? sol25luacuritiba?

Comment: Não entendo porque sempre que aparece um novato, que ainda não detém plena compreensão do funcionamento do stark, disparam a dar pontos negativos a ele. Deveria ser o contrário estimular o aprendizado para que ele tb se torne membro dessa comunidade e no futuro ajude! +1 @sol25lua só da proxima vez postar a pergunta formatada!

Comment: Se a url tiver mais de um parâmetro você pode acessar os valores pelo nome dado na url, no seu exemplo acima acessaria $_GET['nome'] teria o valor sol25lua e $_GET['cidade'] teria o valor curitiba. $_GET e $_POST são variáveis de escopo global do php. Portanto podem ser acessadas de qualquer parte do script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variável `$_GET` é uma **super-global** usada para pegar valores da *querystring*.

Querystring, seria qualquer coisa que vier depois do `?` na URL, exemplo:

```
http://site.com/pagina?foo=bar&baz=foobar
```

Poderiam ser pegos assim:

```
echo $_GET['foo']; //Exibe bar
echo $_GET['baz']; //Exibe foobar
```

E muito provavelmente `$_GET['path']` é usado por um `.htaccess` (ou outro sistema que use mod_rewrite, como nginx ou lighttpd) para reescrever a URL, algo como:

Se for .htaccess (apache):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rotas.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

O `(.*)` pega a URL que for digitada e reescreve passando com parametro para `path=<rota>`, o usuário enxerga algo como:

```
http://site/foo/bar/baz
```

Mas no back-end é executado:

```
http://site/rotas.php?path=foo/bar/baz
```

O que lhe permite criar "URL amigáveis", muito provavelmente você esta usando esse framework MVC:

- https://github.com/luizomf/TutsupMVC/blob/master/classes/class-TutsupMVC.php#L147

Que foi criado pelo [Luiz](https://github.com/luizomf/TutsupMVC) para mostrar um exemplo de como implementar MVC com rotas HTTP.

Comment: Obrigada Guilherme excelente explicação.

Answer (score 0):

Em php $_GET serve para pegar parametros da URL.

Por exemplo se vc requisitar uma pagina como http://meusite.com?path=servicos

$_GET['path'] retornaria a string 'servicos'